# JQuery .load() changing url?

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, function, load

my Question is about the JQuery .load() Function.
I am working on a Website with a Premium Area,
every Link in that Premium Area is checked if its valid.
Example:

```
if  ($wantedPage == "editpw"){$chp=true; include("pages/premium/editpw.php");}
```

$wantedPage is set to the last url part: www.project.org/premium/hereStarts$wantedPage

Thats all Working fine!
Now we try to load a php File via Jquery if a Select is changed.
If the select is changed the function changeMethod() is called.
Here the Method:

```
function changeMethod() {
    var var1 = $( "#var1" ).val();
    var var2 = $( "#var2" ).val();
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#method").load("./pages/vm.php",{
            var1: var1,
            var2: var2
        });
    });
}
```

I did this multiple Times in other Areas on that Webpage it always worked.
Now my Question is does the .load() function change or append the Url? Because when the Function runs I get the Error for accessing a forbidden Area.
I am really confused right now.

Comment: The function is triggered by a `change` event, right? Then why the  `$(document).ready()` in the middle of it?

Comment: The reason is likely caused because of the use of relative URLs. The URL in the load method is probably being appended to the current page's base URL. Just a guess because there isn' really enough info to help you.

Comment: @LouysPatriceBessette The Function is called from the select itself. <select onChange="changeMethod()"> etc

Comment: @RandyCasburn that is exactly my Question does .load() append to the current url? Unfortunately i cant post more Source code ...

Comment: If you use `./` it will append to the path of the current document. If you use '/' it will not append and use the path as an absolute path. Pay close attention the difference is subtle :-)

Comment: The `$(document).ready()` is obviously misused here. The document is ready for a long time when the user triggers a change. It may not be the issue you focus on... But it won't be bad to remove that strangeness.

Comment: Thank You I will try that :)